# Error when using DownloadString from a website using powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

When executing the code below to get a value for a web server I get this error.

I have read some possible solutions that involve changing setting on the web server it’s self but this is not an option for me because I don’t own the server.

**Error**

> Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The server
>   committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine" At
>   C:\get.ps1:28 char:60
>   + $ramPage = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString <<<< ("http://" + $server + "/RAM/" + $evalRAMStars)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

**Powershell Code**

```
Function Get-Performance(){
$CPU = Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average

$SystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Name, TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory
$perRam = (($SystemInfo.FreePhysicalMemory/1MB) / ($systeminfo.totalvisiblememorysize/1MB)) * 100
$perRam = 100 - $perRam

Write-host ("CPU:  " + $CPU.Average + "%")
Write-host ("Ram:  " + $perRam + "%")

$CPUStars = $CPU.Average / 10
$RAMStars = $perRam /10

if($CPUStars -lt 1){$CPUStars = 1}

Write-host ("{0:N0}" -f $CPUStars)
Write-host ("{0:N0}" -f $RAMStars)

$evalCPUStars = "{0:N0}" -f $CPUStars
$evalRAMStars = "{0:N0}" -f $RAMStars

$server = "10.0.0.188"

#this will get our page for later
$cpuPage = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://" + $server + "/CPU/" + $evalCPUStars)
$ramPage = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://" + $server + "/RAM/" + $evalRAMStars)
Write-host("http://" + $server + "/CPU/" + $evalCPUStars)
Write-host("http://" + $server + "/RAM/" + $evalRAMStars)
}

While($x -ne 0)
{
    Get-Performance
    Start-Sleep -s 10   #this will run the powershell script every 10 seconds.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of $evalRAMStars is probably causing the unsafe header parsing to block the message.  Check that its value is valid. Otherwise, see [The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482715/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responsestatusline-error) for more solutions.

Comment: I know there is a valid value in the response. [Setting it programatically:](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/dealing-with-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-sectionresponsestatusline/) seems like it would work but have no idea how to do this in powershell , do you perhaps know ?

Comment: @justinf Can you do `(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://10.0.0.188/RAM/" + $evalRAMStars)` with the value of $evalRAMStars that you are having the issue with? Is $evalRAMStars a number or is there a trailing or leading space or some other character? As for using an app.config file for powershell, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960/powershell-app-config.

Comment: $evalRAMStars contains one charter and that is a 1,I will try just executing (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://10.0.0.188/RAM/" + $evalRAMStars) once i get home later.Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I tryed to run just this and got the same error `$ramPage = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://10.0.0.188:80/RAM/1')` what it should be returning is `RAM Data received.`If i go to the web site using a normal internet browser i see a white page with that text so it seems to be working just no in powershell

Comment: @justinf Or the DownloadString method on System.Net.WebClient (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142403/c-handling-webclient-protocol-violation). Either way, does the fix mentioned above work?

Comment: I will try them later once I am home ,I only had time to try with the URl. I will read through those links you send me and try them out .Thanks again.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work I still got the same erro any ideas `$evalRAMStars = 4
$server = "10.0.0.188:80"



$ramPage = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$config = New-Object  System.net.Configuration.HttpWebRequestElement
$config.set_UseUnsafeHeaderParsing($true)

$ramPage = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://" + $server + "/RAM/" + $evalRAMStars)
`