# DotNetCore WebAPI : problem parsing xml with namespace from Postman

Tags: c#, xml, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a request data which I am getting from some third party, which is in XML. I want to pass this data to C# from postman.

Request XML is as below :

```
<n0:MassMatchQCResponseMsg xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:proxy:TST:/1SAI/TASF64A312341D275609721:740" xmlns:n0="http://example.com/compxref/abctype">
    <MassMatchDet>
        <InputProductNumber>456141</InputProductNumber>        
    </MassMatchDet>    
</n0:MassMatchQCResponseMsg>
```

Here, If I remove namespace alias n0 and post XML, its working fine with the following C# method.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]MassMatchQCResponseMsg value)
{

}
```

but with n0, its showing status 500:Internal server error and fails. Can someone please tell me how to parse xml with namespace from Postman in C#.

Comment: Not sure, but [might be this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142403/c-handling-webclient-protocol-violation)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have your `MassMatchQCResponseMsg` configured with a `Namespace`.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="http://example.com/compxref/abctype")]
public class MassMatchQCResponseMsg{

    [XmlElement(Namespace="")]
    public MassMatchDet MassMatchDet {get;set;}
}

public class MassMatchDet
{
    public string InputProductNumber {get;set;}
}
```

Note the **`XmlRoot.Namespace`**  and **`XmlElement.Namespace`** .

I test with the above code, it just works for me .